# Retrofit is not sending right value to server

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit2, android-image

Here is code that I am using to upload image to server. But its not sending right value like `user_id` so that it shows me wrong result. When I hit api on chrome its working fine it gives proper result. I was using code with uploading Image is :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/queli_technologies/index.php/Webservice")
Call<EditProfileResponse> editProfile(@Part("u_id") String firstname,
                                    @Part("f_name") String lastname,
                                    @Part("l_name") String email,
                                    @Part("c_no") String password,
                                    @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                    @Part("edit_profile") String register);

 RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);

                service = RetroClient.getApiService();


                Call<EditProfileResponse> responseCall = service.editProfile("44","Demo","android","0987654321",body,"edit_profile");

                responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<EditProfileResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<EditProfileResponse> call, Response<EditProfileResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            EditProfileResponse res = response.body();
                            Log.e("Response " , res.getStatus() + " message : " + res.getMessage());
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<EditProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

When i donot get proper result i use this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/queli_technologies/index.php/Webservice")
Call<EditProfileResponse> editProfile(@Part("u_id") RequestBody userId,
                                      @Part("f_name") RequestBody frstname,
                                      @Part("l_name") RequestBody lastname,
                                      @Part("c_no") RequestBody contctnum,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                      @Part("edit_profile") RequestBody edit);


   File file = new File(BaseActivity.basicImagePath);
   RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);

                service = RetroClient.getApiService();
                String text = "31";
                RequestBody useridbody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text);
                RequestBody fnbody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "Demo");
                RequestBody lnbody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "android");
                RequestBody conbody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "0987654321");
                RequestBody isbody =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "edit_profile");

                Call<EditProfileResponse> responseCall = service.editProfile(useridbody,fnbody,lnbody,conbody,body,isbody);

                responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<EditProfileResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<EditProfileResponse> call, Response<EditProfileResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            EditProfileResponse res = response.body();
                            Log.e("Response " , res.getStatus() + " message : " + res.getMessage());
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<EditProfileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Failure Response " , t +"");
                    }
                });
```

Still Im not able get right result. Api response in Log gives `{"status":"0","message":"User doesnot exist"}` when using through retrofit. and from 
server it shows `{"status":"1","message":"User profile Updated"}`

Is this retrofit issue or my coding issue?

Answer (score 0):

Move the file to last.

```
@POST("/queli_technologies/index.php/Webservice")
Call<EditProfileResponse> editProfile(@Part("u_id") String firstname,
                                @Part("f_name") String lastname,
                                @Part("l_name") String email,
                                @Part("c_no") String password,                                    
                                @Part("edit_profile") String register,
                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

I think, it should work.

Comment: No Sir.. same response `0 message : User doesnot exit`

Comment: @PawandeepKaur: Use String instead of Part. Please check the server side code.

Comment: If i use `String` then how can i send image with `@Multipart`?

Comment: @PawandeepKaur : sorry not String, its Query.                                   (at)Multipart
    (at)POST("/ServerCall")
    public void uploadProfilePic((at)Query("requestID") String requestID, (at)Query("pid") String pid,
                                 (at)Part("profile.png") TypedFile file, Callback<StatusResponse> callback);

Comment: Sir @zacharia May you please ans me according to Retrofit 2.

Comment: @PawandeepKaur : I am using Retrofit 2. Your code looks working. You need to check the server code. In the server, if all the value is considering as Multipart, you need to use Part otherwise Query is enough.